# Boost gzip filter Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, gzip

Using the boost library, I was trying to read the gzip file.
but i faced the Segmentation fault error.

may i know what the problem is?

> boost/1.79.0

> Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

```cpp
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> inbuf;
    inbuf.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());

    return 0;
}
```

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

> ==8215==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
> #0 0x56360f5f70c8 in boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::reset() (/root/build/bin/test+0x900c8)
> #1 0x56360f5a14a4 in boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::gzip_header() /root/.conan/data/boost/1.79.0/*/*/package/adf48b8e4446dcb68f440fe42ff08878d5c7feed/include/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp:327
> #2 0x56360f5a29c0 in boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressorstd::allocator<char >::basic_gzip_decompressor(int, long) /root/.conan/data/boost/1.79.0/*/*/package/adf48b8e4446dcb68f440fe42ff08878d5c7feed/include/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp:736
> #3 0x56360f59c091 in main /root/playground/main.cpp:14
> #4 0x7f3063f530b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x240b2)
> #5 0x56360f59bedd in _start (/root/build/bin/test+0x34edd)

Comment: Anyone who want to quickly repro: `git clone https://github.com/sehe/repro73043573 && docker build -t repro73043573 repro73043573 && docker run --rm -it repro73043573`

Comment: Changed my repro to https://github.com/sehe/repro-so/tree/q73043573 - instructions in README. I'm going to do this more often.